# Travelling from Frankfurt airport to Mainz with lot of luggage

Tags: luggage, germany, frankfurt

I will be flying into Frankfurt and from there and I need to travel to Mainz. I will be traveling with my family and we will have a considerable amount of luggage. Could anyone provide recommendations on the best mode of transport to use under these circumstances?

Comment: How many are you and what is “a considerable amount of luggage”? Not everybody has the same notion of that. Also, if there are kids, are they able to handle their own luggage or on the contrary do you need to carry the kids themselves? In other words, what age are they?

Comment: Considerable luggage is 8 bags in my case. One kid aged 6, so not too useful from a luggage carrying perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is already a good answer, but here is some more detail.

1. FRA airport has two train stations, one for local traffic (Regionalbahnhof) and one for long distance travel (Fernbahnhof). You can find trains to Mainz for both stations
2. I strongly recommend taking a direct train from the local station. It's much closer to the terminal and with a local ticket you can take any train on that day. It's only six minutes slower than the high speed train.
3. The S8 (local train line) departs every 30 minutes from track 3 of the local station and takes 26 minutes to Mainz. There are other regional trains in between as well. If you miss a train, just wait for the next one..
4. You can check schedules on bahn.de but you can't buy tickets there (for local train). There are vending machines for tickets.
5. Price is 5.80€ per adult, 3.40€ per child. There is also a 5 person group ticket that's 32.50€ and valid for the entire day (you can travel as often as you like).
6. FRA airport has two Terminals: 1 and 2. The train station is much easier to get to from Terminal 1. From Terminal 2 you will have to take a shuttle or the skyline train. It's a bit of a hike from Terminal 2.
7. There are elevators everywhere and all the trains have level entry. You can avoid steps and stairs.
8. The local trains are doable with luggage. These are commuter trains, so it's mostly for passengers without much luggage, but there is always often an open area when you can stash suitcases. It depends bit on the time of day. In the middle of rush hour, things can get crowded.

Taxi would certainly be more convenient, but depending on your group size and luggage you may want to pre-book something that can accommodate your needs. From the sound of it, you may not fit into a regular taxi. You can try a ride-share like Uber XL. This would also eliminate the need to get from Mainz Hauptbahnhof to your final destination. On the other hand, it will be  more expensive.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 10):

Mainz Hauptbahnof is a 20min train ride direct from one of the airport train stations

This is the most straightforward and least expensive option, but, depending on the luggage amount and the kids' ability to hold/walk, it may be a bit difficult.

As it's only a 30 km ride, you can also take a taxi, this has the advantage of arriving directly at your destination, being able to carry all your bags (Beware that there might be a bag supplement). A site quotes €55 for a day ride from FRA to Mainz.

Comment: Could you add a price for the train connection for comparison? I tried Deutsche Bahn but there also seems to be a regional or S-Bahn connection which bahn.de doesn't have a price for.

Comment: @quarague: price is 5.80€ per adult, 3.40€ per child as per my answer.